# Html Image maps

Tags: html, image, dictionary, area

I am trying to make an image map in html, but for some reason it just will not work.

My code:

```
<img id="Image map" src="Koala.jpg" border="0" usemap="#koala" alt="" />
    <map id="koala">
        <area shape="rect" coords="438,370,552,583" href="http://www.google.com/" alt="Koala nose">
    </map>
</ol>
```

Yes, it is inside an ordered list, not sure if that would contribute to anything.

The image I am referencing (Koala.jpg) is here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OYZV.jpg

When I run the html file everything is there, except the koala is just not clickable at all.

Comment: Looks OK to me - the nose is clickable http://jsfiddle.net/euB4E/

Comment: Weird... doesn't work for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the map name - see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `name="koala"` in addition to the id for Chrome and Safari to work too - http://jsfiddle.net/L4kUm/

```
 <img id="Image map" src="http://i.imgur.com/bZHlxCg.jpg" border="0" usemap="#koala" alt="" />

 <map id="koala" name="koala">
 <area shape="rect" coords="438,370,552,583" href="http://www.google.com/" alt="Koala nose">
 </map>
```